# HAProxy mysql configuration

Tags: centos, load-balancing, haproxy

I tried few times, but I cannot figure it out why my mariadb load balancer with haproxy is not working.
I have :

- 1 HAProxy (CentOS) : 10.181.102.249
- 1 Master (CentOS) :   10.183.241.150
- 2 Slaves (CentOS) : 10.182.2.50 & 10.181.164.36

HAproxy conf :

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  dontlognull
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

listen mysql-read 0.0.0.0:3307;
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option tcpka
    option httpchk
    server db2 10.182.2.50:3306 check port 9201 inter 1s rise 1 fall 1
    server db3 10.181.164.36:3306 check port 9201 inter 1s rise 1 fall 1
    #server db1 10.183.241.150:3306 check port 9201 inter 1s rise 1 fall 1
    server db1 10.183.241.150:3306 backup

listen mysql-write 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy
    balance roundrobin
    server db1 10.183.241.150:3306 check

listen stats :1981
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth test:test
```

I disabled firewalld, and be sure that iptables is not installed, as well selinux not working, to make my test first to know if this is working.

but when I am trying to connect :

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -P 3307 -p -e "show variables like 'server_id'";
```

or

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -p -e "show variables like 'server_id'";
```

I get :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

From a remote server to the haproxy as well the same.

If I list port from haproxy server i get :

```
[root@haproxy ~]# netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21261/haproxy       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3307            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21261/haproxy       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1294/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1533/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1981            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21261/haproxy       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1294/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1533/master
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the stats page say that the servers are up?

Answer (score 3):

As your error message shows, the `mysql` command is trying to connect via a UNIX socket, not a TCP socket, and consequently ignores the port number. This is what `mysql` does if you give `localhost` as the host argument. Try using `-h 127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: I said the same thing, but your explanation is *way* better..

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL client isn't trying to connect via the IP of the system, but rather with the socket file, probably defined in your `my.cnf`. Since the service isn't running locally, it's not going to work.

Try using using the IP when connecting:

```
mysql -h10.181.102.249 -uuser -P 3307 -p -e "show variables like 'server_id'";
```

or

```
mysql -h10.181.102.249 -uuser -p -e "show variables like 'server_id'";
```

Comment: If that's the case, can you accept the answer?